# Prove the converse of Wilson's Theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

... namely that if $n > 1$ and $(n − 1)!\equiv−1\pmod{n}$, then $n$ is prime.

This is for a number theory class I'm in at Penn State. My idea is to follow accordingly, but I can't get it concretely..

Reason by contradiction, suppose that $n$ is not prime.

Then $n = ab$, where $1 < a, b < n$

In particular $(n-1)! = ai$ for some $i\in\Bbb{Z}$. $\\$
If $(n-1)! = nj - 1$ for some $j\in\Bbb{Z}$ then it follows that a probably doesn't divide $-1$?

Comment: Wilson's theorem is an "if and only if" - what is the "converse" of it?

Comment: @GlenO  [If $p$ prime then...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson's_theorem).

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem#Composite_modulus

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have the basic idea, and got almost to the end.

Let  $n$ be composite. Then there exist integers $a$, $b$, with $1\lt a \lt n$, such that $ab=n$. Since $a\ne n$, it follows that $a$ divides $(n-1)!$.

If the "Wilson" congruence holds for $n$, then  $(n-1)!\equiv -1\pmod{n}$.  Thus $(n-1)!=qn-1$ for some $q$.

But $a$ divides both $(n-1)!$ and $n$.  It follows that $a$ divides $-1$. This is impossible, since  $a\gt 1$. So we have shown that if $n$ is composite, we cannot have $(n-1)!\equiv -1\pmod{n}$.