# Dividing $2012!$ by $2013^n$

Tags: number-theory

What's the largest power $n$ such that $2012!$ is divisible by $2013^n$?

It doesn't look like its divisible at all since $2012<2013$; am I right?

Comment: http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Factorial_Divisible_by_Prime_Power

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20737/prime-powers-that-divide-a-factorial

Comment: it's too complicated for me to comprehend

Comment: Also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/363738/prove-the-converse-of-wilsons-theorem

Comment: You would be right if $2013$ was prime. But $2013=3\times 11\times 61$.

Comment: I forgot you can factor 2013, how do you know if 2013 is prime or not?

Comment: @JongSui Quick way to see that it isn't: add the digits

Comment: You can tell right away that its divisible by 3 if you add the digits in the number (2+0+1+3=6), and the result is divisible by 3. Since 6/3=2, which is a integer, then you know 2013 is divisible by 3 as well.

Comment: That only works for $3$ and $9$ for summing up the digits to check for divisibilities

Comment: More generally, it works for factors of $b-1$ in base $b$.

Comment: @Bitwise How is 9! divisible by 100 (10^2)? 9! is divisible by 10^n only for n=0..1

Answer (score 46, accepted):

$2013=3 \times 11 \times 61$. Thirty-two naturals $ \leq 2012$ are divisible by $61$ and none are divisible by $61^2$. At least thirty-two naturals are divisible by $11$ and by $3$, and so we have that $2013^{32}$ divides $2012!$ but no larger power of $2013$ does.

Answer (score 12):

We have $2013=3\times11\times61$. $2012!$ has $\left\lfloor\frac{2012}{3}\right\rfloor=670$ terms in the product that are multiples of $3$, $\left\lfloor\frac{2012}{11}\right\rfloor=182$ terms that are a multiple of $11$ and $\left\lfloor\frac{2012}{61}\right\rfloor=32$ terms in the product that are multiples of $61$. Therefore  $2012!$ only has $32$ "$61$"s that can be cancelled off by $61$ of $2013$. So the maximum value for $n$ is $32$.

Answer (score 4):

Maximum power of $61=$ in  $2012!=\left\lfloor\frac{2012}{61}\right\rfloor$ is $32$ ,maximum power of $11$ in $2012!$ is $61\times 3-1=\left\lfloor\frac{2012}{11}\right\rfloor$, maximum power of $11$ in $2012!$ is $11\times 61-1=\left\lfloor\frac{2012}{3}\right\rfloor$

So the minimum of these numbers will be the maximum power of $2013$ that divides $2013!$

I have used the fact that maximum power of $p$ a prime dividing $q!$ is $=\left\lfloor\frac{q}{p}\right\rfloor$.$\left\lfloor\frac{}{}\right\rfloor$ is the greatest integer function.

Answer (score 2):

A pedestrian approach would be to ask [WolphramAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=FactorInteger%5b2012!%5d&dataset=) to determine prime factors of $2012!$. And since $2013=3\times11\times61$, the answer to your question is $n=32$.