# Proof related with prime numbers and congruence

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

How to (dis)prove this

$ (n-2)!  \equiv 1 \mod  n$

If n is said to be a prime number. I guess we'll have to use FERMAT’S LITTLE THEOREM, and I just don't know where to start from. Thanks in advance

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/363738/prove-the-converse-of-wilsons-theorem

Comment: $$n=4\;,\;\;(n-2)!=2!=2\neq 1\pmod 4$$

Comment: but 4 is not a prime number!

Comment: Exactly @BlediBoss, so your claim is false **unless** you *require* $\;n\;$ to be a prime. Check my answer.

Comment: @DonAntonio that looks promising :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $\;n=p\;$ is a prime, then by Wilson's theorem

$$\color{red}{-1}=(p-1)!=(p-2)!(p-1)=\color{red}{-(p-2)!\pmod p}\implies 1= (p-2)!\pmod p$$

Comment: I forgot to ask, how did you make that pass, I mean how do you eliminate $ (p-1) $

Comment: @BlediBoss , $\;p-1=-1\pmod p\;$ , of course.

Comment: But do we need a proof for it?

Comment: @BlediBoss, it folllows *directly* from the definition of modular equality! $\;a=b\pmod p\iff p\mid (a-b)\;$ , so in our case $\;p-1=-1\pmod p\iff p\mid(-1-(p-1))\iff p\mid p\;$...what, do you think this is trivial or what? :)

Comment: Great job buddy.